# SharePoint 2013 search not working in https site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, https

I have created a  web application which uses port 80 and i have extended the web application at port 443 which is a  SSL enabled site

Example:

1. `http://myportal` (port:80  -Default Zone -Windows Auth)
2. `https://myportal` (port:443 -Intranet Zone -ADFS authentication)

I have added the **http** web application to the local SharePoint site's content source.I ran a full crawl and tried searching in **http** site,the search works fine but when i search in **https** site,its displays "unknown error".

Kindly let me know if I need to do any more configuration for https search to work?

Please note: I am using a service account as the default content source account.

Below is the error in ULS Log:

```
Site Enumeration Stack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBaseCollection.GetEnumerator()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.UrlMapper.GetNewCacheEntry(Pair`2 properties)     at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.UrlMapper.GetUrlMapping(QueryProperties properties, UrlZoneOverride urlZoneOverride)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.Execute(QueryProperties properties)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Query.ExecuteQuery()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueryInternal(Query query)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(Query query)     at Microsoft....
...Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueries(Dictionary`2 queries, Boolean handleExceptions)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass16.<ExecuteQueries_Client>b__14()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.RunWithRemoteAPIsPermission[T](Func`1 f)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueries_Client(String[] queryIds, Query[] queries, Boolean handleExceptions)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutorServerStub.ExecuteQueries_MethodProxy(SearchExecutor target, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutorServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& is...
...Void)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList args, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.InvokeMethod(Object obj, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, Boolean& isVoid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessMethod(XmlElement xe)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessOne(XmlElement xe)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessStatements(XmlNode xe)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessExceptionHandlingScope(XmlElement xe)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessOne(XmlElement xe)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client....
...ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessStatements(XmlNode xe)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.Process()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequestServiceImpl.ProcessQuery(Stream inputStream, IList`1 pendingDisposableContainer)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequestService.ProcessQuery(Stream inputStream)     at SyncInvokeProcessQuery(Object , Object[] , Object[] )     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)...
...     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext request, Boolean cleanThread, OperationContext currentOperationContext)     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext request, OperationContext currentOperationContext)     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)     at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)     at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)     at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)     at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(Item item, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)    ...
... at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(T item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonChannelAcceptor`3.Enqueue(QueueItemType item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.CompleteParseAndEnqueue(IAsyncResult result)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.HandleParseIncomingMessage(IAsyncResult result)     at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.SyncContinue(IAsyncResult result)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.BeginProcessInboundRequest(ReplyChannelAcceptor replyChannelAcceptor, Action dequeuedCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)     at System.ServiceMo...
...del.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.HttpContextReceivedAsyncResult`1.ProcessHttpContextAsync()     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.BeginHttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action acceptorCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)     at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)     at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()     at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()     at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object state)     at System.ServiceModel.AspNetPartialTrustHelpers.PartialTrustInvoke(ContextCallback callback, Object state)     at System.ServiceModel.Activation...
....HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequestWithFlow(Object state)     at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)     at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)     at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)  
[Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 09/28/2016 04:18:41.19, Original Level: Verbose] Claim provider does not support user keys. Claim Provider: '{0}'
[Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] Looking up {0} site {1} in the farm {2}
[Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 09/28/2016 04:18:41.26, Original Level: Verbose] Found valid trusted provider. Provider: '{0}'
[Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] Claim provider does not support user keys. Claim Provider: '{0}'
[Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 09/28/2016 04:18:41.32, Original Level: Verbose] {0}
[Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] SPSecurityTokenServiceManager!GetProviderByName: Returning Trusted Login Provider for input {0}
[Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 09/28/2016 04:18:41.38, Original Level: Verbose] {0}
[Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] SPSecurityTokenServiceManager!GetProviderByName: Returning Trusted Login Provider for input {0}
Leaving Monitored Scope (SearchExecutor.ExecuteQuery). Execution Time=288.7594
Leaving Monitored Scope (SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueries). Execution Time=300.8971
Leaving Monitored Scope (SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueries_Client). Execution Time=300.9274
Exception occured in scope Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueries. Exception=System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.UrlMapper.ExtractMapping(Pair`2 properties, SPSite site, IDictionary`2 urlMapping, IDictionary`2 reverseUrlMapping)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.UrlMapper.GetNewCacheEntry(Pair`2 properties)     at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.UrlMapper.GetUrlMapping(QueryProperties properties, UrlZoneOverride urlZoneOverride)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.Execute(QueryProperti...
...es properties)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Query.ExecuteQuery()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueryInternal(Query query)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(Query query)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueries(Dictionary`2 queries, Boolean handleExceptions)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass16.<ExecuteQueries_Client>b__14()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.RunWithRemoteAPIsPermission[T](Func`1 f)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueries_Client(String[] queryIds, Query[] queries, Boolean handleExceptions)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutorServerStu...
...b.ExecuteQueries_MethodProxy(SearchExecutor target, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutorServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList args, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)
Original error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.UrlMapper.ExtractMapping(Pair`2 properties, SPSite site, IDictionary`2 urlMapping, IDictionary`2 reverseUrlMapping)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.UrlMapper.GetNewCacheEntry(Pair`2 properties)     at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.UrlMapper.GetUrlMapping(QueryProperties properties, UrlZoneOverride urlZoneOverride)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.Execute(QueryProperties properties)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Query.ExecuteQuery()     at Mi...
...crosoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueryInternal(Query query)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(Query query)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueries(Dictionary`2 queries, Boolean handleExceptions)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass16.<ExecuteQueries_Client>b__14()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.RunWithRemoteAPIsPermission[T](Func`1 f)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueries_Client(String[] queryIds, Query[] queries, Boolean handleExceptions)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutorServerStub.ExecuteQueries_MethodProxy(SearchExecutor target, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext pro...
...xyContext)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutorServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList args, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)
Leaving Monitored Scope (Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueries). Execution Time=301.2108
Got exception 'System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.UrlMapper.ExtractMapping(Pair`2 properties, SPSite site, IDictionary`2 urlMapping, IDictionary`2 reverseUrlMapping)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.UrlMapper.GetNewCacheEntry(Pair`2 properties)     at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.UrlMapper.GetUrlMapping(QueryProperties properties, UrlZoneOverride urlZoneOverride)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.Execute(QueryProperties properties)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Query.ExecuteQuery()     at Mic...
...rosoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueryInternal(Query query)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(Query query)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueries(Dictionary`2 queries, Boolean handleExceptions)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass16.<ExecuteQueries_Client>b__14()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.RunWithRemoteAPIsPermission[T](Func`1 f)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueries_Client(String[] queryIds, Query[] queries, Boolean handleExceptions)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutorServerStub.ExecuteQueries_MethodProxy(SearchExecutor target, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext prox...
...yContext)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutorServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList args, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.InvokeMethod(Object obj, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, Boolean& isVoid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessMethod(XmlElement xe)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessOne(XmlElement xe)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessStatements(XmlNode xe)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Cl...
...ientMethodsProcessor.ProcessExceptionHandlingScope(XmlElement xe)' when executing '<ExceptionHandlingScope Id="101" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/clientquery/2009"><TryScope Id="103"><Method Name="ExecuteQueries" Id="105" ObjectPathId="99"><Parameters><Parameter Type="Array"><Object Type="String">84662e3b-396b-47b2-a702-cc7fba659cc8Default</Object></Parameter><Parameter Type="Array"><Object ObjectPathId="74" /></Parameter><Parameter Type="Boolean">true</Parameter></Parameters></Method></TryScope><CatchScope Id="107" /></ExceptionHandlingScope>'.
Original error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.UrlMapper.ExtractMapping(Pair`2 properties, SPSite site, IDictionary`2 urlMapping, IDictionary`2 reverseUrlMapping)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.UrlMapper.GetNewCacheEntry(Pair`2 properties)     at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.UrlMapper.GetUrlMapping(QueryProperties properties, UrlZoneOverride urlZoneOverride)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.Execute(QueryProperties properties)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Query.ExecuteQuery()     at Mi...
...crosoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueryInternal(Query query)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(Query query)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueries(Dictionary`2 queries, Boolean handleExceptions)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass16.<ExecuteQueries_Client>b__14()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.RunWithRemoteAPIsPermission[T](Func`1 f)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueries_Client(String[] queryIds, Query[] queries, Boolean handleExceptions)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutorServerStub.ExecuteQueries_MethodProxy(SearchExecutor target, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext pro...
...xyContext)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutorServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList args, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.InvokeMethod(Object obj, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, Boolean& isVoid)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessMethod(XmlElement xe)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessOne(XmlElement xe)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessStatements(XmlNode xe)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.C...
...lientMethodsProcessor.ProcessExceptionHandlingScope(XmlElement xe)
serviceHost_RequestExecuted
```

Comment: Check what error u get in ULS log?

Comment: @anilpal I have added the ULS log to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got a solution for my search issues. Dismounting and Mounting the MySite content DB again fixed the issue for me.Not sure what was the issue exactly but this solved it for me. I expect some my site may not have upgraded while migrating from SP2010 to SP2013.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I wanted to comment in the event other people come across this. I am a support engineer at Microsoft and have seen this on several occasions.

The reason dismounting your DB and mounting it back worked, is because when u detach the DB, it removes ALL entries out of the SiteMap table in the config DB. When you mount it, it builds that siteMap table back up with its sites from the Sites table in the Content DB..

That ExtractMapping method builds its UrlMapping cache from the entries in the SiteMap table and does so for ALL Web Apps and content DBs during this call. I have seen where you can see this error on lets say web app 1, http://foo1, but the Null Obj Ref, was stemmed from some stale objects on a diff web app...

we generally recommend the following Action when u hit this

```
foreach($db in Get-SPContentDatabase) 
{
    $db.RefreshSitesInConfigurationDatabase() 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@George

Assuming your farm has not more than one SharePoint Server and you have completed the next steps

1) [Config SSL for SP2013](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fabdulwahab/2013/01/20/configure-ssl-for-sharepoint-2013/)

2)  [Add SSL to a Web app](https://griffindocs.wordpress.com/2013/03/20/sharepoint-2013-how-to-add-ssl-to-a-web-application/)

3) [Disabling the SSL warning](https://bcplanning-public.sharepoint.com/Blog/Post/213/Configure-crawler-in-SSL-certificate-warnings-in-SharePoint-2013)

4) Check SharePoint Search Host Controller (SHC)  - service is started

I will start the troubleshooting by run a full crawl and monitor all the search event paying special attention to the mssdmn.exe process and see if some documents from the https address goes throw the indexing.

When at least one or more of those documents have been indexed then you can start to query the SharePoint.

But I am afraid your user account cannot pass the ADFS
I found errors in this class with could means lack of permission

Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.RunWithRemoteAPIsPermission

Try to open IE as search service user account and point the browser to the exact url of one of those documents.

Most likely you cannot open, but if you are able to see it, then the error  come frm another part so you should enable the verboseEx log, for the search events, monitor meanwhile you execute the query and pin down the exact error.
The contamination are almost infinite though you need to troubleshoot a little bit deeper.

```
# Increase Loglevel
Get-sploglevel | where {$_.Area -like “*Server Search*”} | Set-SPLogLevel -TraceSeverity VerboseEx

#Reset loglevel
Clear-SPLogLevel | where {$_.Area -like “*Server Search*”}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly detailed answer on how to dismount/mount content db.

1. For this go to SharePoint Central Administration page (with 36580 port by default): `http://your_company_SP_site:36580/_admin/cntdbadm.aspx

[image]

2. Enter into database configuration
3. Change **Database status** to **Offline** and click **OK** at the bottom
4. Enter into database configuration and change **Database status** to **Ready** again

[image]

After these changes search started working not only with http://sp, but also with https://sp, https://sp.domain.local, http://internet.domain.com (which points to internal ip of SP) addresses.